# Parsing dates in Different format from Text

Tags: python, pandas, regex

i have a dataframe where within the raw text column certain text with Dates in different format is given. i am looking to extract this dates in separate column

sample Raw Text :

> "Sales Assistant @ DFS Duration - **June 2021 - 2023** Currently
> working in XYZ Within the role I am expected to achieve sales targets
> which I currently have no problems reaching. Job Role/Establishment -
> Plasterer @ XX Plasterer’s Duration - **September 2016 - Nov 2016**
> Job Role/Establishment - Customer Advisor @ AA Duration - **(2015 –
> 2016)** Job Role/Establishment - Warehouse Operative @ xyz Duration -
> **03/2014 to 08/2015** In the xyz warehouse  Job Role/Establishment - Airport Terminal Assistant @ port Duration - **01/2012 - 06/2013**
> Working at the airport . Job Role/Establishment - Apprentice Floorer @
> YY Floors Duration - **DEC 2010 – APRIL 2012** "

Expected Dataframe :

```
id      Raw_text                   Dates
01     "sample_raw_text"         June 2021 - 2023 , September 2016 - Nov 2016,(2015 – 2016),03/2014 to 08/2015 , 01/2012 - 06/2013, DEC 2010 – APRIL 2012
```

I have Tried below pattern :

```
def extract_dates(df, column):
    # Define the regex pattern to match dates in different month formats
    pattern = r'(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[-,\s]*\d{1,2}[-,\s]*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[-,\s]*\d{2,4}\s*[-–]\s*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[-,\s]*\d{1,2}[-,\s]*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[-,\s]*\d{2,4}'

    # Extract the dates from the specified column
    df['Dates'] = df[column].str.extract(pattern)
```

with above i am unable to fetch required output. please guide what am i missing

Comment: use regexr.com its very helpful, but if I answer with the right regex please upvote me :D

also, when using complex patterns like this, it is very helpful to split each pattern up into different subpatterns, then pass them into one massive regex string rather than write one massive regex string. It will help you identify which patterns are working and which are not. Just use the OR operator to seperate each subpattern

Comment: sure will upvote :-) please guide

Comment: This is a very complex regex so I probably won't write it for you, sorry man :) But please create a flowchart and organise the regex so it is easier for you. For example, you have three patterns you want to start capturing: Starts with day, month, or year. In these patterns, you then have the potential for new variation: is there a day following ? is there a year following? is there more? Once you have a flowchart that describes the pattern, you can easily create a regex that will match. It just requires some patience and to layout all possibilities.

Comment: Basically i would begin by constructing a "false" regex. Ie; r'(day)?(sep)?((month)?(year)?)+(sep)... etc and once this makes sense logically you can begin to substitute the "day" with the actual patterns for day ie \d?\d should match single digit days and two digit days. I dont know the exact syntax at the moment but this is the approach I would use to ensure that I cover all bases with my pattern

i would make it easier for myself by storing day , month etc as variables containing the pattern definition, so when i go to construct the re string I can actually f string it substituting them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\(?(?:\b[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*)?(?:\d\d?\/){0,2}[12]\d{3}\)?\s*(?:–|-|[Tt][Oo])\s*\(?(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*)?(?:\d\d?\/){0,2}[12]\d{3}\)?|\(\s*[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*[–-]\s*[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*[12]\d{3}\s*\)
```

- `\(?` an optional `(`.
- `(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*)?` non-capturing gruop.

  - `[A-Za-z]{3,9}` between `3-9` letters.
  - `\s*` zero or more whitespace character.
  - `?` makes the whole group optinal.
- `(?:\d\d\/)?` non-caputring group.

  - `\d` a digit between `0-9`.
  - `\d` another digit between `0-9`.
  - `\/` a literal forward slash `/`.
- `[12]\d{3}\s*`

  - `[12]` match one digit from the listed digits `1` or `2`.
  - `\d{3}` three digits between `0-9`
  - `\s*` zero or more whitespace character.
- `(?:–|-|[Tt][Oo])\s*`

  - `(?:–|-|[Tt][Oo])` match `–`, `-`, `TO`, `to`, `To` or `tO`.
  - `\s*` zero or more whitespace character.
- `(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}\s*)?` explained above.
- `(?:\d\d\/)?` explained above.
- `[12]\d{3}` explained above.
- `\)?` an optional `)`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbwfI9/1)

Comment: thanks.!! what changes to be made if dates like (12/03/2020)-(2/11/2021) are to fetched

Comment: @Roshankumar Thank you! updated See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2FsoBB/1)

Comment: kudos..!! @SaSkY  One last can u plz update to fetch this formats as well  (December- March2022) , (July-December 2019)

Comment: @Roshankumar Updated, See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbwfI9/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help buddy..!! stuck with this formats  05/22 - 2023 , 10/21 - 05/22 how to fetch..??

Comment: @Roshankumar Glad to help! See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLze5b/1)

Comment: 31 October 2015 - 28 September 2019 , 07 January 2020 - 31 January 2022 this one :-(

Comment: @Roshankumar See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ywZ9j2/1)